# ROS Answers SE migration: rosbag API c++

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm writing a piece of code that is reading a bagfile, creating a new one, copying all the messages I'm interested from the old one to the new one, and adding a couple of topics more.

Until here everything is fine, but I would be able to copy all the messages from the old bagfile, without having to know the name of the topics and the type of message, but I can't find the way to do this with the C++ API...

I copy a piece of code just to illustrate the way my code works:

```
rosbag::Bag bag_read;
rosbag::Bag bag_write;
bag_read.open(old_bag, rosbag::bagmode::Read);
bag_write.open(new_bag, rosbag::bagmode::Write);

// First we copy all the topic we need to the new bagfile.

rosbag::View view_all(bag_read);    

BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view_all){
    if (m.getTopic() == "/nav/odometry"){
            nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr odom_msg = m.instantiate<nav_msgs::Odometry>();
            if (odom_msg != NULL){              
                ros::Time   time= m.getTime();
                bag_write.write("/nav/odometry", time, odom_msg);
            }
     }
    else if .... /* For every topic I'm interested on */
```

Thank you!!

SOLVED:

As Lorenz says there is no need to instantiate the message:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view_all)
     bag_write.write(m.getTopic(),m.getTime(),m);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49489/rosbag-api-c++/) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-30**:
Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-30**:
To mark answers as correct, klick on the little checkmark below the downvote button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just don't instantiate the message but write the message instance itself. It should implement the Message C++ interface, i.e. provide all required traits so it should be no problem to write it directly. The MessageInstance also provides information about the topic, MD5 sum and message definition.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1